# RadioButton Repeater asp.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater, radio-button

I've added a radiobutton to a repeater in asp.net. I've made the group names work with some Javascript. The problem I am having is when I click save button, the radionbutton.Checked is always false. I can't get the radio button to hold it's checked value.

Comment: It might help if you provided the Repeater code that sets up the RadioButton

Comment: ...also, the code that's trying to check the value of the RadioButtons

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not "reloading" the repeater on "post back".